# I am not getting correct even and odd of the given number using function

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace::std;

int iseven(int a)
{
    if (a / 2 == 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int num;
    cin >> num;

    if (iseven(num)) {
        cout << "number even";
    }
    else {
        cout << "odd h number";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am expecting even and odd of the number, but I am  getting odd as a only output. help me

Comment: You should use `a % 2` instead of `a / 2` in your test.

Comment: 2/2 is 1, 4/2 is 2, 6/2 is 3, ...

Answer (score 1):

You need to compute `a modulo b` to find the remainder of `a / b`. Modulo operator is `%`.
Also, replace return type of the function with `bool`.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

bool iseven(int a)
{
    return a % 2 == 0;
}

int main()
{
    int num;
    cin >> num;

    if (iseven(num)) {
        cout << "even";
    }
    else {
        cout << "odd";
    }
    return 0;
}
```